# Live server extension don't work when I click

Tags: visual-studio-code, server, localhost, port, live

I checked plenty of possible solutions, but I could not run Go Live extension so far. Default browser: chrome (in JSON file), environment variables are including related names (https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/65), live server setting: host (default value 127.0.0.1).

Also, I uninstall this extension, and installed it again, nothing changed. Both Go Live symbol ( in the below) and open with live server (right-click) don't respond when I clicked.
Lastly, I tried to type "http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html", then I faced "This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect."
By the way, I'm opening index.html file within a folder in the vscode.  So I don't know what should I do. If anyone has suggestions, I would like to hear and try.

[default app chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKguQ.png)

[extension setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNney.png)

*setting.json*

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Palenight High Contrast",
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "remimarsal.prettier-now"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "liveServer.settings.https": {
        "enable": true
    },
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0,
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
    "liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false
}
```

***Edit***: I wanted to add the following information because it solved my problem. Please reach the Vscode --> Manage --> Settings --> Extension --> Live Server Config --> Settings:https --> Change value of enable as a false.